# Frontcontroller is not working properly in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, front-controller

I have created module(Admin) completely in zend framework. Now I want to start work in front end so I can manage my whole site from backend. But I am unable to getting solution for this. If I run my page at localhost, then it automatically call the css of backend and theme of backend with error message 'Exception Information', Here I am putting my application.ini file code

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

admin.bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/admin/Bootstrap.php"
admin.bootstrap.class = "Admin_Bootstrap"

appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

resources.session.name = "ZendSession"
;resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session"
resources.session.use_only_cookies = true
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 86400

resources.layout.layout = "layout"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
admin.resources.layout.layout = "admin"
admin.resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/admin/layouts/scripts"


resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
resources.view.basePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/"
resources.view[] =

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] =
resources.view[] =
admin.resources.view[] = 

resources.db.adapter = Pdo_Mysql
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password = 
resources.db.params.dbname = myproject
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true

[staging : production]


[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

In bootstrap file I doesn't have initialization of any function or plugin

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{


}
```

I have created separate bootsrap.php file for module admin like this:-

```
<?php
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    /*protected function _initAppAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'names pace' => 'admin',
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/admin/'
        ));
        return $autoloader;
    }*/

    protected function _initDoctype()
    {
      global $adminModuleCssPath;
      global $adminModuleJsPath;
      $this->bootstrap( 'view' );
      $view = $this->getResource( 'view' );

      $view->headTitle('Projects for learning');
      $view->headScript()->appendFile($adminModuleJsPath.'jquery-1.7.2.js');
      $view->headScript()->appendFile($adminModuleJsPath.'jquery-ui.js');     
      $view->headScript()->appendFile($adminModuleJsPath.'tinybox.js');
      $view->headScript()->appendFile($adminModuleJsPath.'common.js');
      $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet($adminModuleCssPath.'jquery-ui.css');
      $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet($adminModuleCssPath.'style.css');
      $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet($adminModuleCssPath.'theme.css');
      $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet($adminModuleCssPath.'tinybox.css');
      $view->doctype( 'XHTML1_STRICT' );
      //$view->navigation = $this->buildMenu();
    }

    protected function _initLayoutPlugin()
    {
         $layout = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
         $layout->registerPlugin(new Admin_Plugin_AdminLayout());

    }

    protected function _initAuthPlugin()
    {
       $checkAuth = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
       $checkAuth->registerPlugin(new Admin_Plugin_CheckAuth(Zend_Auth::getInstance()));
    }

    protected function _initRouter()
    {
        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $router = $frontController->getRouter();
        $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                 ':module/:controller/:action/*',
                 array('module' => 'admin')
              );
        $router->addRoute('default', $route);

        $usersRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
                      ':module/:controller/:action/(?:/page/(\d+)/?)?',
                      array(
                            'module' => 'admin',
                            'controller' => 'users',
                            'action' => 'index',
                            'page' => 1,
                            ),
                      array(
                              'page' => 1,
                            )
                    );

        $router->addRoute('users-index', $usersRoute);

    }

    protected function _initActionHelpers()
    { 
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(APPLICATION_PATH . "/modules/admin/views/helpers");
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPrefix('Admin_View_Helper');
    }

    /*protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
            'namespace' => '',
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH."/modules/admin",
            'resourceTypes' => array(
                'form' => array(
                    'path' => 'forms',
                    'namespace' => 'Form',
                ),
                'model' => array(
                    'path' => 'models',
                    'namespace' => 'Model',
                ),
            )
        ));
        return $autoloader;
    }*/

}
```

Where I have made error, I don't know, I am new with Zend Framework, please anyone help me to resolve my this problem, so I can call my front site controllers and actions and manage it with backend module(admin)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap classes for *all* modules are called on every request.

If you need to perform module-specific settings (initializing your view, for example), then register a front-controller plugin with a `routeShutdown()` hook. At that point in the dispatch cycle, you know which module is being called so you know how you want to configure your view.

For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9533263/131824) and MWOP's post on [ZF1 module bootstrapping](http://mwop.net/blog/234-Module-Bootstraps-in-Zend-Framework-Dos-and-Donts).